# How reliable is FLORIS to calculate downstream turbine turbulence intensity?

Tags: floris

I'm using FLORIS to obtain individual turbine wind speed and wind turbulence intensity in a wind farm. At first I tried with FAST.Farm but due to the limited amount of wind turbines I had to change to FLORIS. The main difference that I'm seeing with a row of turbines is that in FAST.Farm the turbulence intensity changes from the first turbine upwind to the ones behind, but keeps a constant (more or less) turbulence intensity in the rest of turbines, whereas in FLORIS turbulence intesity increases from one turbine to the next one.

For example, in a row of 9 turbines, if I have a 10% turbulence intensity (lets call it TI) in the 1st turbine the 2nd could have around 25% TI, and the ones behind this would have similar TI values. In the case of FLORIS 1st turbine TI is 10%, 2nd turbine TI is 25%, 3rd turbine TI is 35%, 4th turbine TI is 45%...
In some cases almost reached a 100% TI for the last turbine.

FAST.Farm case seems more logical to me so why does FLORIS do that? Am I introducing any input parameter wrong?

I'm using the next values for Crespo-Hernandez parameters in FLORIS:

config.wake.properties.parameters.wake_turbulence_parameters.crespo_hernandez.initial = 0.0325
config.wake.properties.parameters.wake_turbulence_parameters.crespo_hernandez.constant = 0.73
config.wake.properties.parameters.wake_turbulence_parameters.crespo_hernandez.ai = 0.8325
config.wake.properties.parameters.wake_turbulence_parameters.crespo_hernandez.downstream = -0.32

for the following range of parameters 5 < x/D < 15, 0.07 < I, < 0.014 and 0.1 < a < 0.4

Comment: Well, I am not quite sure how FAST.Farm works, but I guess that I might have a clue what could be the answer. The Crespo&Hernandez is a turbulence induced model which calculates the added turbulence produced by the perturbation of the upfront rotor, I guess from what you described, such model is not yet implemented in FAST.Farm.

Answer (score 0):

In the latest version of FLORIS we've re-tuned the Crespo-Hernandez model parameters to the set of LES data we have accumulated.  The current default values are:

```
    default_parameters = {
        "initial": 0.1,
        "constant": 0.37,
        "ai": 0.8,
        "downstream": -0.275,
    }
```

There is alternatively provided the Ishihara-Qian model from:

Ishihara, T., & Qian, G. (2018). A new Gaussian-based analytical wake model for wind turbines considering ambient turbulence intensities and thrust coefficient effects. Journal of Wind Engineering & Industrial Aerodynamics, 177(August 2017), 275–292. https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jweia.2018.04.010